# Need to move a 12v DC, 1.5 ohm resistance circuit (power window motor) into another vehicle with a .8 ohm motor

Tags: motor, dc, resistance, 12v

In the past, when I have tried to cut down the voltage from a variable solar panel into a DC motor with a 10 watt resistor, the resistor always got too hot.

This case is a somewhat different; a solid 12v DC source and a computer that is apparently looking for 1.5 ohms and all it sees is 0.8 ohms from the new power window motor.

This question arises from a restomod project where I am moving most of the electronics, engine, wiring harness, interior, dash, etc. from a 2014 Camaro into a 1970 Malibu.

How would you fool the computer and still allow the motor to function?

---

Somehow I missed the below response, mea culpa.

It's the body control module (BCM) in a newer Camaro.

---

Here's a pic of the semantics in the service manual...

[image]

Comment: 0.7 ohms in series? Should fool the electronics but might leave the motor a little wimpy. Cheap and easy to try though.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that "a computer that is apparently looking for 1.5 ohms." What gave you that idea? Which computer are you talking about?

Comment: pcguy - Hi, Your "answers" (which weren't answers to your original question, and therefore should not have been posted in the "Your Answer" box) have been added to the question as edits i.e. updates. Unless you are writing the full answer to your own question (i.e. you have solved the problem yourself, with no further help needed) please don't use the "Your Answer" box below. Instead [Edit] the question to add new information. This is part of the "Stack Exchange "philosophy" and is one way that it differs from typical forums. See the [tour] and [help] for more rules. Thanks! (Any questions?)